# How to add a path to manpath.config without changing the system setting?

Tags: manpage

I am used to the old style `MANPATH`.  But it does not seem to exist on Ubuntu.  Instead the file `/etc/manpath.config` is used.

I have some man pages in my home directory `~/man`. How to add this directory to the manpath configuration without changing the system setting?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
echo MANDATORY_MANPATH ~/man > ~/.manpath
```

But `apropos` still does not work.

Comment: You have to execute `mandb` to make `apropos` work.